# Appy If statement in the pivot filter

Tags: vba, excel

[image]

In this, not all the time, I will have the option 12L or 03A when I pull the report. How do I apply an if statement which would filter (deselect) only when these options are available.

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Purchasing Group")
    .Orientation = xlPageField
    .Position = 1
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Item").CurrentPage = "10"
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Purchasing Group"). _
    CurrentPage = "(All)"
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Purchasing Group")
    .PivotItems("03A").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("12L").Visible = False
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Purchasing Group"). _
    EnableMultiplePageItems = True
Range("A7").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").InnerDetail = "Contract"
Selection.ShowDetail = True
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.Refresh
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Purchasing Group")
    .PivotItems("03A").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("12L").Visible = False
End With
```

generates error when "03A" and "12L" are not available. You can just add `On Error Resume Next`.

```
On Error Resume Next 'In case of error, go to next line
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Purchasing Group")
    .PivotItems("03A").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("12L").Visible = False
End With
On Error GoTo 0 'Disable any enabled error handler
```